# How to use "await" for a generator function is ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

## The issue

I'm curious if it would be possible to consume a **generator**-function in **async**/**await** context within modern ES2017. *(The application is a React-native-application)*

This is my code where I want to call the generator function:

```
class ProductViewComponent extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await loadProduct(...)
    console.log(result)  // Gives: *Generator* and not the final result
  }

}
```

The function `loadProduct()` was imported from another file and is defined as follows:

```
export function * loadProduct(id) {

   let product = yield select(productByIdSelector(id));
   if(!product) {
      // ... yield this
      // ... yield that
      // ... finally:
      product = yield call(loadProductFromWeb, id) 
   }
   return product;
}
```

## The concrete question:

As far as I know I can use `await` to await results from Promises. How can I use generator functions in this context?

Comment: gen = loadProduct(); await gen.next();

Comment: apparently the .next() gives many results for each "yield"-statement within the loadProduct-Function (there are many yield-statements inside, more than displayed in the question)

Comment: i still dont get the usecase? What does the generator return? Promises?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating from Generators to Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579282/migrating-from-generators-to-async-await)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it its a coroutine yielding (some) promises. Assuming the real result is simply the last result of the coroutine, and you cannot change the generator code, you can iterate the generator and await everything - Promises will be awaited and undefineds will be ignored.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const resultGenerator = loadProduct(...);

  let result;

  for (let task of resultGenerator) {
    result = await task ;
  }

  console.log(result); // should be last result of coroutine
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `await` here? It should do the same without it.

Comment: Because its yielding promises - see `call(loadProductFromWeb...`

Comment: Where does the OP say it returns promises?

Comment: Its an educated guess due to "loadProductFromWeb"